# ISO file missing from the downloaded version

Tags: 14.04, mount

i downloaded the ubuntu 14.04 edition and when i extracted it there was no ISO file and squashFS is around 938 MB, is that the installation file,how do i extract it,  if so how do i mount it on a USB stick. Thank you

Comment: What are you downloading if not the iso itself?

Comment: Squashfs is a compressed format of a file. This link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mMXzgzHeE4 is a reference for you. Check whether you have missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong... you download the iso file, then you write it to a USB drive (or cd/dvd), then you boot it (if you want to run live / install Ubuntu).

1. Download the iso of Ubuntu (from http://www.ubuntu.com/download ) or Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc, have their own sites. (Should verify the iso too, using md5)
2. Write the iso to usb. See [Ubuntu's help wiki on installing from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows) for instructions for doing it on  linux, mac, windows. Good page, might want to read it all.

   (http://pendrivelinux.com has good writing tools for windows too)